# copy database setup from one project to another

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using intllij and every now and then I have to setup a new project which uses the 
same or similar datasources to a previous project.

Is there a simple way to copy them across?

Comment: Already asked and answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934918/sharing-databases-between-projects-within-intellij/57255435#57255435

Comment: @AndreyDobrikov only 3 1/2 years after this question. just saying

Comment: Well I looked for an answer myself only yesterday, and saw your post, just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either move a data source to a shared, global data source, or you can copy them as a separate data source (added somewhere in 2017). The first option will keep the consoles etc. shared, the second one will not.

To copy a data source, go to the `context menu` → `Database Tools` → `Copy Data Source to Clipboard`. Then in the other project go the `context menu` → `New` → `Import from Clipboard`.

Comment: In fact this should be accepted answer! Does exactly what was asked.

Answer (score 9):

Under the datasource properties there is a scope in the top right corner.

Change it from PROJECT to IDE

Looks like the interface has changed there is now this button to use
it will move the data source from Project Data Sources to Global Data Sources.
Using it on a Global Data Source will move it to Project Data Sources

[image]

more information [at jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html)

Comment: Looks like the UI for this has changed.  In 2016.2.2 its now a "Make Global" button in datasource properties that seems to do the same thing.