# Sharing databases between projects within Intellij

Tags: database, intellij-idea, sharing, projects

I use Intellij to inspect databases, run sql, view data in tables etc. This all works fine but the only thing I am missing is the ability to define these datasources once and view them in all my projects i.e. that I can share them between other projects and not have to redefine them for new projects. Is this possible in Intellij?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I share settings for IntelliJ Idea across different projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313946/can-i-share-settings-for-intellij-idea-across-different-projects)

Comment: Similar question: can I do this between Jetbrains products? Like import my datasources form DataGrip into Intellij or Pycharm?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Go to the `Database` tool window and click on the `Data Source Properties` button. Select the data source you want to make global. Click on the `Make Global` button in the tool bar above.

The `Make Global` button looks like this:

[image: Make global button]

Now you can use the data source from all your projects. However a global data source is not stored in the project files, so any other developers working on the same project will need to define their own data source.

Answer (score 27):

The `Make Global` button is no longer green (Intellij Ultimate 2018.02).

It's located above the datasource list, as in the (crappy) screenshot.

[image]

Comment: In Intellij Ultimate 2018.2.5 I could not find it

Comment: This icon is present in "Data Sources and Drivers" window

Answer (score 11):

In Intellij 2020.1, click on the Database view, then click on "Data Source Properties" (database with wrench icon). On the dialog that opens, click on "Make global", which is the 5th icon (screenshot below).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

In IntelliJ 2019.1, 2019.2 to share connection to DB with multiple projects:

1. [Open Database panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfQkt.png)
2. [Datasource Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I8pq.png)
3. [Make Global](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoK6L.png)

Answer (score 1):

So how I did it on 2018.3 was to go to the Database tool window then right click on your datasource you want to copy then Database Tools -> Copy Datasource to Clipboard. In the Database window for the project you want to copy to click the + at the top left and it has an option to Import from Clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ 2019.3 to share connection to DB with multiple projects:

. Open Database panel
. Data source Properties
. Click the blue`Make Global` button

[image: View this image to see where it is]